# How to update an item in core data

Tags: iphone

I am using Core Data. I retrieve data in a NSMutable array using some NSPredicate. Now I want to update some items. Let say I have a name string or some BOOL which I want to update. So how to do that. Like Is there any way I can update with respect to ID or something, becoz I dont get all the items from the managedObjectContext.

Answer (score 2):

You assign the data to the objects. and then call

```
[managedObjectContext save:&error];
```

on each the respective context object. You can call

```
[managedObject managedObjectContext];
```

to get that items context

To get a managed object with a certain id you use
NSFetchRequest and it's setPredicate method. then something like this

```
[request setEntity:[NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Shirt" inManagedObjectContext:moc]];
NSArray *shirtsInDB = [moc executeFetchRequest:request error:nil];
```

or this method in NSManagedObjectContext

```
- (NSManagedObject *)objectWithID:(NSManagedObjectID *)objectID
```

Comment: How to get the managedObject. Like lets say I want to retrieve the managed object with id =10 then how to do that.